# Beginner Java Multithreading issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with a Java multithreaded file crawler that I am making. My issue is that I have a workQueue that is a linkedBlockingQueue that contains the names of files that I would like to crawl over with my threads, each thread will `take()` from the workQueue and while scanning through the file it may `put()` another file name into the workQueue (It is a dependency checker program). So I am never really certain when the work is all finished and all threads will eventually enter a waiting state when they try to `take()` from the (eventually) empty workQueue.

So I guess my question is, is there an efficient way to terminate all of threads once all of the work is finished (when all of threads have entered a waiting state)? Currently I just use `sleep()` on the main thread and then `interrupt()` all of the worker threads.

Sorry if the question sounds confused.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, and the only way I found was to send a special marker object to the `BlockingQueue`. When the Queue `.take()` the object, if this is the marker, then the `Thread` ends itself.

I've tried other solutions, like to wake up the thread and detect the Exception, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pattern called the [Poison Pill](http://www.captaindebug.com/2013/03/producers-and-consumers-part-3-poison.html#.VlKCK-Jlbik) that's good for this. Basically, when the producers are done, insert a special value into the queue that tells a consumer to stop. You can either insert one pill for each consumer, or, once a consumer gets a poison pill, return it to the queue for the next consumer. Since it sounds like you're just enqueuing strings, something like

```
public static final String POISON_PILL = "DONE";
```

Or in Java 8, use `Optional` to wrap your values, then have not present be the pill.

```
BlockingQueue<Optional<...>> queue;
```

Another option is using an `ExecutorService` (which is actually backed by a `BlockingQueue`) and submitting each file as its own task, then using `executorService.shutdown()` when you're done. The problem with this is that it couples your code more tightly than needed, and it makes it harder to reuse resources like database and HTTP connections.

I'd avoid interrupting your workers to signal them because that can cause blocking IO operations to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the approch below. Add observer pattern if you need to.
Or simply - instead of signalling with a death packet, collect a list of waiting Threads and then interrupt() them.

```
public class AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue<T> {

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<T>    mWrappingQueue                  = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private final Object                    mSyncLockObj                    = new Object();

    private final int                       mMaxBlockingThreads;
    private final T                         mDeathSignallingObject;

    private volatile int                    mNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop    = 0;

    public AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue(final int pMaxBlockingThreads, final T pDeathSignallingObject) {
        mMaxBlockingThreads = pMaxBlockingThreads;
        mDeathSignallingObject = pDeathSignallingObject;
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        final T retVal;
        synchronized (mSyncLockObj) {
            ++mNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop;
        }
        synchronized (mWrappingQueue) {
            if (mNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop >= mMaxBlockingThreads && mWrappingQueue.isEmpty()) signalDeath();
            retVal = mWrappingQueue.take();
        }
        synchronized (mSyncLockObj) {
            --mNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private void signalDeath() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mMaxBlockingThreads; i++) {
            mWrappingQueue.add(mDeathSignallingObject);
        }
    }

    public int getNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop() {
        return mNumberOfThreadsInAccessLoop;
    }
}

class WorkPacket {
    // ... your content here
}

class MultiThreadingBoss {
    static public final WorkPacket  DEATH_FROM_ABOVE    = new WorkPacket();

    public MultiThreadingBoss() {
        final int THREADS = 7;
        final AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue<WorkPacket> prioQ = new AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue<>(THREADS, DEATH_FROM_ABOVE);
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            final ThreadedWorker w = new ThreadedWorker(prioQ);
            new Thread(w).start();
        }
    }
}

class ThreadedWorker implements Runnable {
    private final AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue<WorkPacket> mPrioQ;

    public ThreadedWorker(final AccessCountingLinkedPrioQueue<WorkPacket> pPrioQ) {
        mPrioQ = pPrioQ;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                final WorkPacket p = mPrioQ.take();
                if (p == MultiThreadingBoss.DEATH_FROM_ABOVE) break; // or return

                // ... do your normal work here

            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sincere thanx for the downvotes people. But in God's name, please leave a comment why this is bad, so we all learn.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, but I'd manage the threads with an ExecutorService.